# how haskell catch throwIO called exception in ExceptT

Tags: haskell

when use monad transformer `ExceptT` to wrapper the `IO Monad`.

and then `throwIO e` in the inner IO monad,

so how this exception was catch by outer `Exception` and converted to and `Either e a` Type one

for example:

my program define type :

newtype HandlerT e a = HandlerT { runHandlerT :: ExceptT e (ReaderT (IO a)) }

then when in inner IO monad do the HTTP request to access and no-existen web site, the innert http.LBS will throw exception by call throwIO.

then ,

```
runExceptT $ runReaderT $ runHandlerT (http.LBS "http://notexist.com")
```

will return an `Either e a`

the e has the exception the inner call throw out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `safe-exceptions` package (tutorial at: https://haskell-lang.org/library/safe-exceptions), which provides a set of functions which will help here in two ways:

1. They are lifted to work in many different monads, including `ExceptT` and `ReaderT`. Note that you will likely need to derive instances for `MonadThrow` and `MonadCatch` for your `HandlerT`.
2. You can use the `catchAny` and `tryAny` functions to catch all synchronous exceptions, which is probably what you want here. (See the linked tutorial for more information on synchronous vs asynchronous.)

That said: given that the `httpLBS` function is (most likely) living in `IO` itself, you can also do something like:

```
liftIO (tryAny (httpLBS req))
```

and avoid the need to bother with runtime exceptions in a monad transformer at all.